# What is the "correct" method of locating caves in Ark: Survival Evolved?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I played Ark: Survival Evolved for about 4 months and found absolutely no references or traces of any of the caves during normal playthrough.

I never once stumbled across one, or found anything "in game" that mentioned them or directed me to them.

The only way that I found out where they were was by looking up an online guide and even then it was difficult to find some of them.

When playing through the game, what is the "correct" method for locating caves. Surely it's not just stumbling across them.

Answer (score 1):

You can locate only underwater caves, according to [Ark wikia](https://ark.fandom.com/wiki/Caves):

> There are currently 12 Resource Caves on The Island, and are all found underwater. The only indication of the position from the surface is a small flow of bubbles, appearing as a thin white line, and huge seaweeds.

There's no easy method to find caves on land, unfortunately. Caves are supposed to be hard to find, you actually have to stumble across them (or find their location on the Internet).

As many users on Reddit suggest, the game is meant to be played with friends. In that case everyone can scout areas and you work together. If you are doing just single player, you will burn out before you find them all.